# Disable directory indexing for all directories using root htaccess

Tags: htaccess, wordpress

How to disable directory indexing for all directories using root htaccess?

Using this line `Options -Indexes` only disable listing on directory where the htaccess put.

I'm sure there's a lot of directories that need the listing disabled and it's better if i can use single root htaccess to do that.

Comment: The parent .htaccess file on the filesystem is always inherited by subdirectories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `Options -Indexes` on root htaccess will disable indexing for its sub folder. Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use cPanel, you can change the setting through there:

1. Select Advanced > Indexes (might be called Index Manager depending on your version of cPanel)
2. Click public_html (or whatever your web root is)
3. Select No Indexing
4. Click Save